# Search array in text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, external

I currently have a javascript (with jQuery) program that finds a value `x`. I have also generated, via Python, a separate database of some 28,000 arrays of values, which I would like to search inside of using javascript to effectively find the position in the database of the found value `x`.

The database is currently stored as a separate text file and is an array of arrays. I would be looking at the Nth element of each array in the database array for the `x` value. Is this kind of searching through an external file easy to do with Javascript? Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Easy, yes. Fast and scalable, absolutely not.

Comment: haha thank you! Are you able to describe the process briefly?

Comment: Use AJAX to get the text from the file (assuming your server allows direct file access, otherwise you'll need some server side logic to return the file contents) then it's just a simple loop through the returned array to find the index of the items matching `x`. As I mentioned above, this will be incredibly slow, though. First you have to download all the 28k nested arrays, then you have to loop through them all - and that's per request. In all the ways you could do achieve what you're attempting, this is just about the worst. I'd suggest you do this server side using a database, if possible

Comment: Yes I see what you mean! What is it then that you would suggest with respect to "server side", this isn't something I am familiar with. I am open to all suggestions, as faster is faster.

Comment: PHP, C#, Python itself.

Comment: Ahh, I see. The only thing is that it is an html/javascript app that is hosted on my website, so ideally it would all run in the browser. Seems like then PHP maybe makes the most sense?